# How is "ja" used?

Tags: word-usage

In a discussion on lernu.net, I read that somebody claimed that *ja* could only be used in *jes ja*. I tend to use it like an emphasis marker, and I believe I've heard others use it similarly.

Is this acceptable?

These are the best examples I could think of right now:

*Ĉu vi scias ĉu li ŝatas pastaĵon?*
*Ne vere, sed li ja estas italo, ha ha.*
*Mi ankoraŭ ne decidis ĉu mi iru aŭ ne. Mi ja volas, sed eble mi ne havos sufiĉe da mono.*

Comment: Do you have a link to that discussion?

Comment: Right now I don't, but I haven't really searched. I could try to find it if that would be valuable.

Comment: It might be helpful to see what was said in that thread, but it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can certainly be used in other contexts besides "*jes ja*"; here are some examples from Zamenhof's translation of Andersen's fairy tales ([*Fabeloj de Andersen*](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Fabeloj_de_Andersen))

- > *"Tio tute ne estas via afero!" diris la sorĉistino, "vi ricevis **ja** monon, nun donu al mi nur la fajrilon."*
- > *"Aŭskultu, botisteto! vi ne bezonas tiel rapidi", diris al li la soldato, "oni **ja** nenion faros, antaŭ ol mi venos."*
- > *la malgranda Niko ne povas **ja** forkuri, kaj ĉiuj homoj estas en la preĝejo.*
- > *Vi vidis **ja** la belajn cignojn, kiuj alnaĝas al vi, kiam vi volas doni al ili eretojn da pano.*
- > *Tial mi nun diros al vi ion, pri kio la profesoro de botaniko, kiu loĝas proksime de ĉi tie - vi lin **ja** konas? - tre forte mirus.*

So you see "*ja*" is used for emphasis in a variety of contexts, not just "*jes ja*".

Answer (score 6):

*Ja* can translate to "indeed" (*Jes Ja* -> "yes indeed") or "do" ("I like pizza" vs. "I do like pizza"). In general, it is uses to emphasize the veracity of a statement, and can certainly be used outside of *Jes Ja*.

See PMEG: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/ja.html